# changing the intervals of two variables of a data set in r

Tags: r

I have two variables. The data collected for one variable ranges from 0 to 100 and another variable ranges from -1 to +1. How do I change the interval of one variable from 0 to 100 to -1 to +1 in R?

Comment: Did you try `(x/50)-1`?

Comment: I guess Negative values doesnt make sense for that variable. You can simply divide by 100, or use log10 values in order to get both variables in the same range.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values where you want to split your groups, you may use a recode-function, e.g. from the [car](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) or [sjmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjmisc/index.html) package.

```
library(sjmisc)
x <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace = T)
y <- rec(x, "min:33=-1; 34:67=0; 68:max=1")
table(x, y)
```

You can also use the base `cut` function, however, it returns the value as `factor`.

```
y <- cut(x, 3)
levels(y) <- c("-1", "0", "1")
table(y)
```

With `as.numeric(y) - 2` you have values from -1 to 1 again.

If you want to set the range from .1 to 1, instead of having a range-difference of 2 (from -1 to 1), you have a range-difference of .9 (from .1 to 1). So I simply calculated the proportion, which is `2 / .9`. (old range-diff / new range-diff).

Your solution would be (sloppy hack...)

```
# your values copy / pasted
dummy <- c("1 0 0.06 -0.58 -0.87 -1 -0.77 -1 -0.62 0.83 -0.86 -0.83 0.42 -0.6 1 0.47 0.94 0.23 0.46 -0.98 -0.04 -0.39 0.99 0.81 0.11 -0.85 -0.56 0.14 1 -0.79 -0.06 -0.58 0.79 0.71 -0.2 0.69 -0.33 0.64 -0.76 0.14 -0.41 1 -0.83 0.01 -0.86 -0.65 -0.58 0.5 -0.39 -0.8 -0.36 0.17 -0.96 -0.46 -0.78")
# convert to numeric vector
dat <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(dummy, " ", fixed = T)))
# new range from .1 to 1
dat / (2 / .9) + .55
```

Comment: How do I convert for each data entry?

Comment: is1
0
0.06
-0.58
-0.87
-1
-0.77
-1
-0.62
0.83
-0.86
-0.83
0.42
-0.6
1
0.47
0.94
0.23
0.46
-0.98
-0.04
-0.39
0.99
0.81
0.11
-0.85
-0.56
0.14
1
-0.79
-0.06
-0.58
0.79
0.71
-0.2
0.69
-0.33
0.64
-0.76
0.14
-0.41
1
-0.83
0.01
-0.86
-0.65
-0.58
0.5
-0.39
-0.8
-0.36
0.17
-0.96
-0.46
-0.78 
My data set looks like this, now how do I convert the scale to 0.1 to 1?